# holidays module not found in exe file pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-holidays

I coded a small project in Python using tkinter GUI and the module holidays.
I am thus using pyinstaller through anaconda to generate an unique .exe file for my python script.
I used a virtualenv generated through ananconda for the entire project and am using the modules:
pandas and holidays

I launched pyinstaller a first time and ran into an issue that was: no module named openpyxl found which I was able to solve using stackoverflow. The following command solved it:
`pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import openpyxl.cell._writer -w`

However, after that i got the same kind of error with holidays module:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "kiesel_gui.py", line 3, in <module> import kiesel_simulator File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module File "kiesel_simulator.py", line 5, in <module> import seasonality_builder as src File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module File "seasonality_builder.py", line 4, in <module> import holidays ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'holidays'`

I was not able to find any thread on here related to the holidays module and pyinstaller so I just modified the previous command:
`pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import openpyxl.cell._writer --hidden-import holidays -w`

This does not work unfortunately, i still get the same error when i launch my application file.
Can anybody help me please and tell me what i am doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot

I modified the command that worked for openpyxl in vain

Comment: create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you can try with --hidden-imports:

hiddenimports=['holidays', 'holidays.utils', 'holidays.calendars', 'holidays.countries', 'holidays.groups']

this solves my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).